# Conditionally writing to different output files

Tags: python, if-statement, with-statement

I have customizable script that can give up to 3 different output files depending on what is requested. Currently I have:

```
with open("option1", "w") as file1, open("option2", "w") as file2, open("option3", "w") as file3:
```

The issue I'm running into is if the option is not selected, the file is still being created  (because of the open statement) which is what I'd like to avoid.

Naively what I think I want is an allowed syntax along the lines of the following that would be allowed:

```
with (if type1: open("option1", "w") as file1), (if type2: open("option2", "w") as file2), (if type3: open("option3", "w") as file3):
```

The 3 different types and corresponding options are not mutually exclusive, it is common to want more than 1 of the file types. The type1, type2, and type3 variables are booleans that are set to False by default and toggled independently to True at the command line. Overall I'm trying to efficiently avoid the creation of empty files, and am open to even fairly drastic changes in code to accomplish it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
filenames_map = {"type1":"option1", "type2":"option2", "type3":"option3"}
filename = filenames_map.get(type, "default_option")
with open(filname, "w") as targetFile:
    # do whatever needs to be done
```

[`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) gets value from the dictionary and defaults to second argument of no such key found.

If types are not mutually exclusive it's a little bit trickier. [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is a compound statement, so under normal execution flow (no exceptions) these two are roughly equivivalent:

```
with (context_manager) as something:
    do_stuff()  

try:
    context_manager.__enter__()
    do_stuff()
finally:
    context_manager.__exit__()
```

So, if you can't determine the number of files to write to until runtime, you'll have to manage context yourself. Luckily, `open` returns [`FileObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), hich are context managers with `__enter__` and `__exit__` defined. Luckily, `open` returns [`FileObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) which is a quite simple context manager. As stated in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close)

```
with open("hello.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line,
```

Is equal to

```
f = open("hello.txt")
try:
    for line in f:
        print line,
finally:
    f.close()
```

Now, to the point

```
target_files = []
# please modify to follow PEP-8 yourself, compressed for clarity
if user_wants_type1(type): target_files.append("option1")
if user_wants_type2(type): target_files.append("option2")
if user_wants_type3(type): target_files.append("option3")

try:
    handles = [open(filename) for filename in taget_files]
    for handle in handles:
        handle.write("something")
finally:
    for handle in handles:
        handle.close()
```

Comment: I'm trying to do some testing with this, but it seems this can only write to a single file? Also type1, type2, and type3 are different variables False by default and set as True at the command line rather than a single variable set to a specified value. will update question to reflect some of this

Comment: @ded updated to allow writing to multiple files. In order to work with `type1`, `type2`, `type3` as distinct variables just replace `if user_wants_typeN(type): ...` with `if typeN: ...`

Comment: this is nice, still somewhat limited in that each handle is opened separately so I'd have to step through the same "something" for each of the 3 handles. I'd take any suggestions on that, but I am going to lean towards reworking the "something" so that it is sorted into the 3 different types as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python3, you could use [contextlib.ExitStack:](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/contextlib.html)

```
import contextlib
filenames = ['option{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,4)]
types = [type1, type2, type3]

with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(filename, 'w'))
             for filename, typ in zip(filenames, types) if typ]
```

For Python2, you could use the [contextlib2 module](http://contextlib2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

Can it be more than one type at once? If not, I'd set up a conditional prior to writing to the file like this:

```
if type1:
    fname = "option1"
elif type2:
    fname = "option2"
elif type3:
    fname = "option3"

with open(fname, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("ok!")
```

Comment: The 3 types are not mutually exclusive. Someone may want any combination of all 3 types, commonly options 2 and 3 are selected together but don't have to be.

Answer (score 0):

I would just figure out the file before you do any opening at all.

```
if type1:
    filename = "option1"
elif type2:
    filename = "option2"
elif type3:
    filename = "option3"

with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
    #do stuff
```

Comment: The 3 types are not mutually exclusive. In other words, someone may want any combination of all 3 types.